# Help Creating a 'Complex' ERD

Tags: database-design, erd

I am stuck on how to represent the relationships I need correctly. I have a
**Produce** table. Each type of produce—e.g., 'lettuce'—has one or more quantity suffixes that can be associated with it, e.g., 'boxes' or 'heads.' Furthermore, the produce table has one or more varieties, e.g., 'green' or 'red.'

So you can have

**Produce:** lettuce

**Quantity Suffixes:** heads, boxes, and packs

**Varieties:** green and red

So if you were filling it out, you would choose lettuce, then have the ability to choose green or red for varieties, and then heads, boxes, or packs for the quantity suffix.

Thank you for any help.